# Permission denied: '/usr/sbin/authserver'

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm getting

`[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/sbin/authserver'`

after  running:

`python3 setup.py py2app` in terminal

My setup.py file is:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['FileManagerApp.py']
DATA_FILES = [('data', '/Users/admin/Desktop/File_Manager/data/file_paths.txt')]
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

This was working perfectly earlier today, but then just stopped.

It's my understanding that on Mac OSx 11.5.2 I can't change the permissions to just grant access to '/usr/sbin/authserver', and the error occurs when py2app calls the modulegraph package, specifically the listdir function in the zipio module when it gets to '/usr/sbin/authserver'.

Is there a way to make listdir skip this folder in the listdir function to not error out due to not having permission? Am I missing a setting in py2app? This happens both in a venv and not.

Is there a way to go back in time/revert my machine to the time when py2app was working as I just need to get this app packaged?

Comment: *Why* does your `setup.py` want to do something with `/usr/sbin/authserver`?

Comment: I don't know, but I know previously, it wasn't an issue, and then all of a sudden it was.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is getting raised because, the file which setup.py is calling, is owned by root (or whatever the superuser is in mac), and its permissions of reading and writing (probably) are not set for groups and others, so we have to give it permissions for that

For mac users (proabably because I don't use mac os I use linux but as far as I know they have almost similar syntax) and linux users:

`sudo python3 setup.py`

For Linux users:

`sudo python3 setup.py`